# mod_rewrite backreferencing within RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to have multiple backreferences on RewriteRule when having multiple RewriteCond?

For example, I have

```
# Cookie value
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user_lang=([^;]+)$ [NC]
# /path/to/image/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*/)[^/]*$ [NC]
# filename.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
```

Now I want to make this work:

```
RewriteRule .* %2%3/%1 [R,L]
```

But I can only get the LAST condition result. Is it really possible to have %2, %3, %N or only the last one (%1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for `.htaccess` then you should be able to do this with 1 rule for the last two conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user_lang=([^;]+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/$2/%1 [R,L]
```

Be careful trusting user supplied data.